# Extracting uppercased and camelcased words using regex

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string:

`Beyonce Knowles is married to Jay-Z and KANYE WEST is awesome and San Antonio Texas is great but not as good as West Palm Beach, FL`

I need to extract `Beyonce Knowles`, `Jay-Z`, `KANYE WEST`, `West Palm Beach, FL` and `San Antonio Texas` (separated)

I'm still new to regex, but so far I've got `'/^[A-Z]+/`

How do I fix my regex to account for the extracted words I am trying to obtain?

Thanks

Comment: You have asked so many regex question, and still don't know what `^` means?

Comment: I am new to regex. I provided what I can do, but this regex is beyond my capabilities.

Comment: those people are horrible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
/\p{Lu}+\p{L}*(?:[\s\p{P}]+\p{Lu}+\p{L}*)*/u
```

This will match one or more uppercase letters followed by zero or more lowercase letters, possibly repeated multiple times, separated by one or more white space or punctuation characters. It takes advantage of [Unicode character classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) so it can handle text in other languages.

Or this to match just two such patterns in a row:

```
/\p{Lu}+\p{L}*[\s\p{P}]+\p{Lu}+\p{L}*/u
```

For example:

```
$input = 'Beyonce Knowles is married to Jay-Z and KANYE WEST is awesome and San Antonio Texas is great but not as good as West Palm Beach, FL';
$pattern = '/\p{Lu}+\p{L}*(?:[\s\p{P}]+\p{Lu}+\p{L}*)*/u';
preg_match_all($pattern, $input, $output_array);
```

Produces the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array 
        (
            [0] => Beyonce Knowles
            [1] => Jay-Z
            [2] => KANYE WEST
            [3] => San Antonio Texas
            [4] => West Palm Beach, FL
        )
)
```

Comment: And what about situations when its completely capitalized, like my example KANYE WEST

Comment: @jkushner for that you can `+` after the `\p{Lu}`. See my update.

Comment: Here is my string: `$string = 'Beyonce Knwoles Jay-Z KANYE WEST';`. Doing a `print_r` leaves me with `Array ( [0] => Beyonce Knwoles Jay-Z KANYE WEST [1] => WEST )` . I need the matches to be separated, such as `Array ([0] => Beyonce Knowles, [1] => Jay-Z, [2] => KANYE WEST)`

Comment: Updated my question to show i need the matches separated

Comment: @jkushner When asking questions about regular expressions, you need to be ***very*** clear about what you to match and not match. See my updated answer for a pattern which will work for that new input.

Comment: I understand and am sorry. Is there a way to account for all the names i need extracted. This edit only accounts for Beyonce Knowles

Comment: I tried replacing the `u` with `g` and i also tried `gu`. Where do I put the global modifier? its throwing an error when i use g

Comment: There is no `g` modifier in PHP. In php to match "globally" you need to use `preg_match_all()` instead of `preg_match()`.

Comment: I just noticed that it limits to two words using the second regular expression. How do I account for N words, such as `San Antonio Texas`. Sorry again I did not reflect this in my question

Comment: @jkushner I don't think you'll be able to find a pattern which will match `San Antonio Texas` but not `Beyonce Knowles Jay`. I recommend you rethink your overall strategy.

Comment: The strategy is correct. I misworded myself. I do need to know how to capture N words that are uppercased and/or camelcased, separated by non-uppercased words

Comment: @jkushner Why don't you [learn regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) so that you can fulfil all your wishes even when you change your mind ?

Comment: @jkushner but earlier you said `Beyonce Knwoles Jay-Z KANYE WEST` should match `Beyonce Knowles`, `Jay-Z`, and `KANYE WEST` separately. This does not fit your description. My first pattern will match **N** words, the second pattern will match only 2 words.

Comment: @p.s.w.g the problem is the first pattern does not separate the words. i updated my question. i need to match N words >= 1 where they are uppercased and then you can separate when its a non uppercased word. Notice I also added a scenario when there are 4 words and its separated by a comma

Comment: @p.s.w.g Can you update your regular expression to include `Blue-ray`. As you can see, I have an uppercase followed by a special character and then ending in a non-uppercased word.